# Grails not-null property references a null or transient value during validate

Tags: hibernate, validation, grails

I have a domain class with a bunch of non nullable strings. For one of the domain properties I call a custom validator which does a database check.  When my original domain object has a field nulled in it, during the custom validate the domain object attempts to flush.  This causing a 'not-null property references a null or transient value' error.  I have my hibernate flush mode set to manual, so I have no idea why it is attempting to flush.

```
    String id
String name
String type
String description


static constraints =
{
    id unique: true, nullable:false
    type unique:false, nullable: false
    name(unique:['type'] nullable: false, blank:false,
        validator:{val, obj ->
            if(val != null)
            {
                    def result = OtherDomain.findByType(val)
                    if(result == null)
                    {
                        return 'foreignkey'
                    }

            }

        })


    description unique:false,nullable: false

}

static mapping =
{
    table 'track'
    id column:'id', type: 'string', generator: 'assigned'
    version false
}
```

There is no other domain modification going on.  This is the only domain edited during this transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails will normally flush the hibernate session before any query, so `OtherDomain.findByType(val)` is causing the flush.  You can work around this by doing the query in a separate hibernate session like this:

```
OtherDomain.withNewSession { session ->
    def result = OtherDomain.findByType(val)
    if (result == null) {
        return 'foreignkey'
    }
}
```

Comment: This cleared it up the issue and its back to validating.  Thanks!